# Right-click menu covered in Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

In Hotmail or Windows Live Mail, you can right click to bring up a menu.

In Firefox, the default right-click menu covers it.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under **tools > options > content > javascript > disable context menus** (in firefox)
you can set this to either block this kind of javascript or enable it.

In your case... you like this and so you enable it meaning: websites may use javascript to create their own context menu.

Comment: Never saw that option before.

Comment: it does not work always: http://www.htmlguard.com/articles/disabling-the-context-menu-in-firefox/